# Determine where Hessian matrix is semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I determine if the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2/y&-2x/y^2\\-2x/y^2&-2x^2/y\end{bmatrix}$ is semidefinite? Could someone please show me an algorithm to show this. I know how to do it when the matrix values are all scalar, but not when there are variables inside of it.

Comment: You want to express your eigenvalues in terms of $x$ and $y$. i.e. Find the characteristic equation in terms of $x$, $y$ and find their eigenvalues. (Actually, you don't need to find the actual values if you can argue what the sign of the two eigenvalues should be.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}2/y&-2x/y^2\\-2x/y^2&-2x^2/y\end{bmatrix}\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$

The characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(X)=X^2-(trA) X+detA=0$

And, 
$tr(A)=\frac{2}{y^2}(1-x^2)$

$\displaystyle detA=-\frac{4x^2}{y^4}\left(y^2+1\right)$

Now, note that $det A<0$ (squares are positive). In particular, the product of eigenvalues $\lambda_1\lambda_2<0$ and that implies that $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are opposite signs.

Hence, it is indefinite. (Actually, we didn't have to calculate the trace in hindsight.)

Comment: Thank you, but what if the product of eigenvalues is greater than 0? Is this when you would use the trace, and how so?

Comment: Also wouldn't the trace be $\frac{2}{y}(1-x^2)$

Comment: Yeah, typo. Let me correct it

Comment: If the product of eigenvalues is positive than, we know the eigenvalues are of the same sign so you need to look at the trace to see if it is positive or negative definite